# sklearn Random Forest accuracy score identical for training and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, metrics

I'm attempting to build a classification model for electric vehicle charging event data. I want to predict whether the charging station will be available at a given point in time. I have the following code working:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:/temp/sample_dataset.csv')
raw_test = pd.read_csv('C:/temp/sample_dataset_test.csv')
print ('raw data shape: ', raw_test.shape)

#choose which columns to dummify
X_vars = ['station_id', 'day_of_week', 'epoch', 'station_city',
 'station_county', 'station_zip', 'port_level', 'perc_local_occupancy',
 'ports_at_station', 'avg_charge_duration']
y_var = ['target_variable']
categorical_vars = ['station_id','station_city','station_county']

#split X and y in training and test
X_train = raw_data.loc[:,X_vars]
y_train = raw_data.loc[:,y_var]
X_test = raw_test.loc[:,X_vars]
y_test = raw_test.loc[:,y_var]

#make dummy variables
X_train = pd.get_dummies(X_train, columns = categorical_vars )
X_test = pd.get_dummies(X_test, columns=categorical_vars)

print('train size', X_train.shape, '\ntest size', X_test.shape)

# Train uncalibrated random forest classifier on whole train and evaluate on test data
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

print ('RF accuracy: TRAINING', clf.score(X_train,y_train))
print ('RF accuracy: TESTING', clf.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Results

```
raw data shape:  (1000000, 15)
train size (1000000, 125) 
test size (1000000, 125)
RF accuracy: TRAINING 0.831456
RF accuracy: TESTING 0.831456
```

My question is why is the training and testing accuracy EXACTLY the same? I've run this many many times, it's always exactly the same. Any ideas? (I've checked the make sure the original data IS different)

Comment: There's no information on the size of `raw_data`. Do you expect to have exactly the same number of observations in both your `raw_train` and `raw_test` sets?

Comment: You are testing and training on the same data. `X_train == X_test` is `True`. Use scikit-learn's `test_train_split` function or some form of cross-validation iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is simply a typo in your code, because each time your select all rows:

```
#split X and y in training and test
X_train = raw_data.loc[:,X_vars] 
y_train = raw_data.loc[:,y_var]
X_test = raw_test.loc[:,X_vars]
y_test = raw_test.loc[:,y_var]
```

You should index them separately by some index for example: `X_train = raw_data.loc[:idx,X_vars]`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using the same set of data in train and test files?

If it's same data, then it might be better to split the data into train and test using train_test_split module.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html